# Derivative of absolute distribuion

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

$(T',\phi) = -(T,\phi')$ is the definition of derivative of distribution function $T$
How to use this to evaluate:

1. $e^{|x|}$
2. $\sin|x|$
3. P($\frac{1}{x}$)

In 3, it is the cauchy principal value. Can I just use any test function? or I have to use specific ones?

Comment: For the first two, note that the functions are differentiable except at $x=0$, so you would, informally, expect that the derivative is given by just differentiating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go by definition, then you should take arbitrary test functions.

For the first distribution, you take a test function $\phi$, suppose that its support lies in $[-R,R]$, then, by definition,

$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{|x|}\phi'(x)dx = \int_{-R}^0 e^{|x|}\phi'(x)dx+\int_{0}^R e^{|x|}\phi'(x)dx = \int_{-R}^0 e^{-x}\phi'(x)dx+\int_{0}^R e^{x}\phi'(x)dx $$
You integrate by parts, because all functions are regular:

$$\int_{-R}^0 e^{-x}\phi'(x)dx = \phi(0) + \int_{-R}^0 e^{-x}\phi(x)dx$$
$$\int_0^R e^{x}\phi'(x)dx = -\phi(0) - \int_0^R e^{x}\phi(x)dx,$$hence
$$\int_{\mathbb R} e^{|x|}\phi'(x)dx = -\int_{-R}^R sgn(x)e^{|x|}\phi(x)dx= -\int_{\mathbb R}  sgn(x)e^{|x|}\phi(x)dx,$$thus, by definition,
$$(\exp(|x|))' = sgn(x)\exp(|x|).$$

The same technique applies for other distributions that you mentioned.